# add offset to the datetime64 column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

this is really a quick one:

i am migrating from q to pandas, i am trying to add 1 nano to each of the item in the Date column of the data frame 'spy'

```
>>> spy
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 126 entries, 0 to 125
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Date      126  non-null values
Open      126  non-null values
High      126  non-null values
Low       126  non-null values
Close     126  non-null values
Volume    126  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(1)
```

for illuatration, i have this 1 nano

```
ttt=np.datetime64(1,'ns')
```

then i try to do:

```
[x+ttt for x in spy['Date']]
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/py6868jTH", line 9, in <module>
    [x+ttt for x in spy['Date']]
TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

can anyone enlight me what's wrong here? ttt and x should be of the same type, right?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add datetimes. You have to use timedelta instead:

```
>>> s  = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2013-11-11', periods=3, freq='D'))
>>> td = np.timedelta64(1,'ns')
>>> s
0   2013-11-11 00:00:00
1   2013-11-12 00:00:00
2   2013-11-13 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> s + td
0   2013-11-11 00:00:00.000000001
1   2013-11-12 00:00:00.000000001
2   2013-11-13 00:00:00.000000001
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: hi, thanks, it works. however, i am still curious to see why i cannot do list comprehension here, what's wrong with [x+td for x in spy['Date']] ?